# Unzip string in JS

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, unzip, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am pulling down objects from s3. the objects are zipped, and I need to be able to unzip them and compare the contents with some strings. My problem is that I can't seem to get them properly unzipped. This is what I am seeing happen: s3 zipped -> over the wire -> to me as JS Buffer -> ???

I am unsure of what I can do next. I have seemingly tried everything, such as pako, and lzutf8 to decompress the strings, but no dice.

here is an attempt with lzutf8:

```
lzutf8.decompress(buffer,{outputEncoding: "String"}, (result, error) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    if (data) console.log(data);
});
```

Here is an attempt with pako:

```
pako.ungzip(buffer,{to: "string"}, (result, error) => {
    if (error) console.log(err);
    if (result) console.log(data);
})
```

pako throws an "incorrect header check", and lzutf8 silently does nothing.

I am not married to these libraries, so if there is anything else that will do the job, I am happy to try anything. I am guessing that my problem might have something to do with the encoding types? Not sure though.

Here is what the relevant part of my code looks like:

```
let pako = require('pako');
let streamBuffers = require('stream-buffers');


let ws = fs.createWriteStream(process.cwd() + 'path-to-file');
let rs = new streamBuffers.ReadableStreamBuffer();
objects.forEach((obj) => {
    console.log(obj);
    rs.on("data", (data) => {
        ws.write(pako.ungzip);
    })
    rs.push(obj);
})
```

Comment: Is it zipped or is it gzipped? These are two completely different things.

Comment: zipped. I guess I don't know the difference. although I was just told we are changing it to gzip...

Comment: [Zip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) is a very specific file format that encodes one or more files and directories. [gzip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) is a compression method that typically is used on an arbitrary data stream or single file. You need to know which type you're trying to deal with, the format is completely different.

Comment: Gotcha. My data is gzipped.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a readable stream from an object in S3 with the AWS SDK's [`createReadStream` method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/requests-using-stream-objects.html) and then pipe that through a [`zlib.Gunzip` transform stream](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html#zlib_class_zlib_gunzip):

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
var s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
var params = {Bucket: <bucket>, Key: <key>};
var file = require('fs').createWriteStream(<path/to/file>);
s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(zlib.createGunzip()).pipe(file);
```